# Pass by reference in C99

Tags: pass-by-reference, c99

I just read [this](http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/oopdocbook/opensource/passreference.html):

> In C++ (and C99), we can pass by
>   reference, which offers the same
>   performance as a pointer-pass.

So I tried this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void blabla(int& x){
    x = 5;
}

int main(){
    int y = 3;
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
    blabla(y);
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
}
```

The output was:

```
gcc test.c -o test -std=c99
test.c:3:16: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
test.c: In function 'main': 
test.c:10:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'blabla'
```

Now I'm confused. Is pass by referenced indeed supported by C99?

Comment: Do we know why C99 have no same concept of C++ reference? Is there somewhere in the C language that would break if such concept is to be absorbed into the language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That page is wrong.  There are no "references" in C (even in C99).

In C, when you want to pass "by reference," you fake reference semantics using a pointer.

Comment: So even C99 doesn't suport pass by reference. Is this stated somewere in the language spec? I tried those n1256.pdf and n897.pdf, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @anta40:  No.  The language spec doesn't have a list of all the possible features that it could have but doesn't.  C doesn't have references because they don't appear anywhere in the spec.