# Convert PyCuda code to PyOpenCL code : How to perform a high number of 3x3 matrix inversion?

Tags: python, gpu, opencl, pyopencl

I try to convert a PyCuda code to PyOpenCL. This is the following of a previous version of working NVIDIA GPU code. This code aims to invert a high number of 3x3 matrixes.

Here's the PyCuda working version :

```
$ cat t14.py
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.autoinit
# kernel
kernel = SourceModule("""

__device__ unsigned getoff(unsigned &off){
  unsigned ret = off & 0x0F;
  off >>= 4;
  return ret;
}   

// in-place is acceptable i.e. out == in) 
// T = float or double only
const int block_size = 288;
typedef double T; // *** can set to float or double
__global__ void inv3x3(const T * __restrict__ in, T * __restrict__ out, const size_t n, const unsigned * __restrict__ pat){

  __shared__ T si[block_size];
  size_t idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  T det = 1;
  if (idx < n*9)
    det = in[idx];
  unsigned sibase = (threadIdx.x / 9)*9;
  unsigned lane = threadIdx.x - sibase; // cheaper modulo
  si[threadIdx.x] = det;
  __syncthreads();
  unsigned off = pat[lane];
  T a  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
  a   *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
  T b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
  b   *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
  a -= b;
  __syncthreads();
  if (lane == 0) si[sibase+3] = a;
  if (lane == 3) si[sibase+4] = a;
  if (lane == 6) si[sibase+5] = a;
  __syncthreads();
  det =  si[sibase]*si[sibase+3]+si[sibase+1]*si[sibase+4]+si[sibase+2]*si[sibase+5];
  if (idx < n*9)
    out[idx] = a / det;
}   

""")
# host code
def gpuinv3x3(inp, n):
    # internal constants not to be modified
    hpat = (0x07584, 0x08172, 0x04251, 0x08365, 0x06280, 0x05032, 0x06473, 0x07061, 0x03140)
    # Convert parameters into numpy array
    # *** change next line between float32 and float64 to match float or double
    inpd = np.array(inp, dtype=np.float64)
    hpatd = np.array(hpat, dtype=np.uint32)
    # *** change next line between float32 and float64 to match float or double
    output = np.empty((n*9), dtype= np.float64)
    # Get kernel function
    matinv3x3 = kernel.get_function("inv3x3")
    # Define block, grid and compute
    blockDim = (288,1,1) # do not change
    gridDim = ((n/32)+1,1,1)
    # Kernel function
    matinv3x3 (
        cuda.In(inpd), cuda.Out(output), np.uint64(n), cuda.In(hpatd),
        block=blockDim, grid=gridDim)
    return output
inp = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
n = 2
result = gpuinv3x3(inp, n)
print(result.reshape(2,3,3))
$ python t14.py
```

And here below my attempt to get the equivalent PyOpenCL version :

```
$ cat gpu_opencl.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

# Initialization
n = 2
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
a_in = np.array(n*9).astype(np.float64)
res_np = np.zeros(n*9).astype(np.float64)
mf = cl.mem_flags
a_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a_in)
res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=res_np)
# kernel
prg = cl.Program(ctx, """

unsigned getoff(unsigned &off){
  unsigned ret = off & 0x0F;
  off >>= 4;
  return ret;
}   

// OpenCL
// T = float or double only
typedef double T; 

const int block_size = 288;

__kernel 
void 
inv3x3(
__global const T* restrict in,
__global T* restrict out,
const size_t n,
const unsigned* restrict pat
)
{
  unsigned int tid = get_local_id(0);
  unsigned int gid = get_global_id(0);
  unsigned int groupid = get_group_id(0);
  unsigned int localSize = get_local_size(0);

  __local T si[block_size];
  size_t idx = tid + groupid*localSize;
  T det = 1;
  if (idx < n*9)
    det = in[idx];
  unsigned sibase = (tid / 9)*9;
  unsigned lane = tid - sibase; // cheaper modulo
  si[tid] = det;
  // Synchronize to make sure data is available for processing
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  unsigned off = pat[lane];
  T a  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
  a   *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
  T b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
  b   *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
  a -= b;
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  if (lane == 0) si[sibase+3] = a;
  if (lane == 3) si[sibase+4] = a;
  if (lane == 6) si[sibase+5] = a;
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  det =  si[sibase]*si[sibase+3]+si[sibase+1]*si[sibase+4]+si[sibase+2]*si[sibase+5];
  if (idx < n*9)
    out[idx] = a / det;
}   
""").build()

def gpuinv3x3(inp, n):
    # internal constants not to be modified
    hpat = (0x07584, 0x08172, 0x04251, 0x08365, 0x06280, 0x05032, 0x06473, 0x07061, 0x03140)
    hpatd = np.array(hpat, dtype=np.uint32)
    # Convert parameters into numpy array
    # *** change next line between float32 and float64 to match float or double
    inpd = np.array(inp, dtype=np.float64)
    hpatd = np.array(hpat, dtype=np.uint32)
    # *** change next line between float32 and float64 to match float or double
    output = np.empty((n*9), dtype= np.float64)
    # Get kernel function
    res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, a_in.nbytes)
    prg.inv3x3(queue, a_g, res_g, np.uint64(n), htpatd)
    res_np = np.empty_like(a_in)
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)
    return res_np

inp = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
n = 2
result = gpuinv3x3(inp, n)
print(result.reshape(2,3,3))

$ python gpu_opencl.py
```

But when I execute this latter with PyOpenCL, I  get the following errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gpu_opencl_inv_3x3.py", line 69, in <module>
    """).build()
  File "/Users/fab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 510, in build
    options_bytes=options_bytes, source=self._source)
  File "/Users/fab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 554, in _build_and_catch_errors
    raise err
pyopencl._cl.RuntimeError: clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE - clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE - clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE

Build on <pyopencl.Device 'AMD Radeon Pro Vega 20 Compute Engine' on 'Apple' at 0x1021d00>:

<program source>:5:26: error: expected ')'
unsigned getoff(unsigned &off){
                         ^
<program source>:5:16: note: to match this '('
unsigned getoff(unsigned &off){
               ^
<program source>:5:10: warning: no previous prototype for function 'getoff'
unsigned getoff(unsigned &off){
         ^
<program source>:5:26: error: parameter name omitted
unsigned getoff(unsigned &off){
                         ^
<program source>:6:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'off'
  unsigned ret = off & 0x0F;
                 ^
<program source>:7:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'off'
  off >>= 4;
  ^
<program source>:15:11: error: global variables must have a constant address space qualifier
const int block_size = 288;
          ^
<program source>:23:26: error: kernel pointer arguments must have a global, local, or constant address space qualifier
const unsigned* restrict pat
                         ^
```

I don't know how to modify exactly the equivalent for PyOpenCL. Someone could see by chance an error in my PyOpenCL code. I am seeking some clues to make this PyOpenCL code working like with PyCuda version.

### Update

Thanks to `@talonmies` comment, I have finally found a solution that seems to work, here's the code :

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

# Initialization
n = 2

# Numpy array
a_np = np.array(n*9).astype(np.float64)
res_np = np.zeros(n*9).astype(np.float64)

# Select a device
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

# Allocate memory on the device and copy the content of our numpy array    
mf = cl.mem_flags
res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, a_np.nbytes)

# kernel
prg = cl.Program(ctx, """

#define block_size 288

static unsigned getoff(unsigned* off){
  unsigned ret = *off & 0x0F;
  *off = *off >> 4;
  return ret;
}   

// OpenCL
// T = float or double only
typedef double T;

//__constant int block_size = 288;
__kernel 
void 
inv3x3(
__global const T* in,
__global T* out,
const size_t n,
__global const unsigned* pat    
)
{
  unsigned tid = get_local_id(0);
  unsigned groupid = get_group_id(0);
  unsigned localSize = get_local_size(0);

  //Get kernel function
  //Define block and grid : NOT USED 
  //blockDim = (288,1,1) # do not change
  //gridDim = ((n/32)+1,1,1)

  __local T si[block_size];
  size_t idx = tid + groupid*localSize;
  T det = 1;
  if (idx < n*9)
    det = in[idx];
  unsigned sibase = (tid / 9)*9;
  unsigned lane = tid - sibase; // cheaper modulo
  si[tid] = det;
  // Synchronize to make sure data is available for processing
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  unsigned off = pat[lane];
  T a = si[sibase + getoff(&off)];
  a  *= si[sibase + getoff(&off)];
  T b = si[sibase + getoff(&off)];
  b  *= si[sibase + getoff(&off)];
  a  -= b;
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  if (lane == 0) si[sibase+3] = a;
  if (lane == 3) si[sibase+4] = a;
  if (lane == 6) si[sibase+5] = a;
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  det =  si[sibase]*si[sibase+3]+si[sibase+1]*si[sibase+4]+si[sibase+2]*si[sibase+5];
  if (idx < n*9)
    out[idx] = a / det;
}   
""").build()

def gpuinv3x3(inp, n):
    # internal constants not to be modified
    hpat = (0x07584, 0x08172, 0x04251, 0x08365, 0x06280, 0x05032, 0x06473, 0x07061, 0x03140)
    # Convert parameters into numpy array
    inpd = np.array(inp, dtype=np.float64)
    hpatd = np.array(hpat, dtype=np.uint32)
    # Create input numpy
    a_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=inpd)
    res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, inpd.nbytes)
    hpatd_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=hpatd)
    #Get kernel function
    my_knl= prg.inv3x3
    my_knl.set_scalar_arg_dtypes([None, None, np.int32, None])
    my_knl(queue, inpd.shape, None, a_g, res_g, n, hpatd_g)
    # Create a numpy array for the results and copy them from the device
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)
    return res_np

inp = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
result = gpuinv3x3(inp, n)
print(result.reshape(2,3,3))
```

That produces the 2 expected matrixes :

```
[[[ 2.         -0.         -1.        ]
  [-1.         -0.33333333  1.        ]
  [-0.          0.33333333 -0.        ]]

 [[ 1.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          1.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          1.        ]]]
```

Now, I am faced to the understanding of the kernel parameters used in PyCuda version, i.e :

```
   # Global and local sizes
   blockDim = (288,1,1) 
   gridDim = ((n/32)+1,1,1)
```

As you can see, I have not used, in my working version above, these parameters : How can I include them into the calling of kernel code ?

I tried to do in the calling :

```
my_knl(queue, gridDim, blockDim, a_g, res_g, n, hpatd_g)
```

It seems that right syntax is :

```
my_knl(queue, globalSize, localSize, a_g, res_g, n, hpatd_g)
```

In CUDA version, the calling with these sizes is :

```
 # Kernel function
    matinv3x3 (
        cuda.In(inpd), cuda.Out(output), np.uint64(n), cuda.In(hpatd),
        block=blockDim, grid=gridDim)
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5359677/681865

Comment: @talonmies . Thanks but example in the link compiles fine with `g++ Apple` clang but not with `gcc Apple clang`. How to handle the C++ convention with PyOpenCL ? (I mean the passing by reference). regards

Comment: You can't --  that is the point. OpenCL is C99 based and C99 doesn't have references

Comment: My bounty ends in few hours, Isn't there really no suggestion of code snippet to help me to do the conversion CUDA --> OpenCL ? Regards

Comment: The problem is that you keep changing the question. The first version was full of elementary syntax errors. The second was about references. Now it is function arguments (hint None is not the same as 0 in Python). Who would waste their time answering this (that is a rhetorical question). [SO] is a place to ask concrete, answerable questions, not a personalized help service. Please don't treat it like one

Comment: I try simply to show my progression in the debug, i.e the different steps to make work this code. There's nothing else except this, just a legitimate approach, I don't treat it like a perzonalized service, and moreover, the solution may help other people to face and solve this kind of issue.

Comment: But this is a question, not a changelog and every edit you have made just make the question harder to read and understand and changed what you are asking. I am extremely skeptical that your latest code version actually compiles because I see an dynamically sized array in the kernel. And if the code actually did run, I would guess the problem lies with the definition of `si`, which you have incorrectly translated between the CUDA and OpenCL

Comment: @talonmies . Thanks, I got it !  It only remains the issue that I describe about the global and local sizes. If you had an idea, this would be nice to tell it. Regards